# Three Pendulum Rotary Harmonograph

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm trying to create a simulation of a three pendulum rotary harmonograph, the one you can see in action in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4YQonwQUDs) video or in [these](http://www.karlsims.com/harmonograph/index.html) instructions.

As you can see in the video, there are 2 pendulum with 1 degree of freedom each (one axis of movement) plus 1 pendulum with 2 degrees of freedom (the one in the middle, holding the sheet of paper).

I'm currently able to simulate the movement of a pen attached to just 2 pendulum (with 1 degree of freedom each) using this formula

[image: 1 axis pendulum]
(t = time, f = frequency, p = phase, d = damping, a = amplitude)

The result of this formula will give me the position of the pen on the x axis. I can then use it a second time with different values to obtain the position of the pen on the y axis. Very straightforward: result is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/5cT4J/embedded/result/).

So, how can I add the third pendulum (the one with 2 degrees of freedom)? This formula can compute the position of a rod connected to a pendulum with two degrees of freedom:
[image]

However, I don't think this is what I need. The formula only gives me as a result one number: the movement of the pendulum makes the sheet of paper move on two axis (and I would even say 3, judging by the fact that the sheet of paper doesn't stay parallel to the plane).

So how in the world do I project the movement of a pendulum moving in 3d space over a 2d plane? Is this what I really need to do? If yes how?

Finally, even assumed that I'm able to do so, how should I insert these results into the pen x and y position? I presume is a matter of just making an addition: am I wrong?

(p.s. please forgive any possible triviality in my question. As you probably have guessed, I've never been taught physics nor computer science)

EDIT:

here's my pain. I can only simulate figures on the left. The one on the right requires a third pendulum, and this third pendulum is not oscillating in just one direction but two (or three?!).. *(Image from "Quadrivium: The Four Classical Liberal Arts of Number, Geometry, Music, & Cosmology")*.

[image]

Comment: +1 for introducing me to an amazingly awesome physical system that I'd never heard of before and what is now one of my favorite YouTube videos!

Comment: Yep, I'm enjoying the "artistic" part of physics. Glad you like it... Try to play around with the simulator I've made. Just change the frequency of one of the pendulum to a multiple of the other and look at it go :) Hope someone may help to put in a third rotatory pendulum!

Comment: The 3-D to 2-D mapping isn't really a problem.  While your system will move in three dimensions, you can reduce the problem to one of 2 coordinates, which greatly improves the solvability of the system.  An equation of constraint gives you the mapping between your 2 dynamical coordinates and your 3 spatial dimensions.  (For example, imagine a marble racing around on the surface of a paraboloid; the marble is moving in 3 dimensions, but it obeys an equation of constraint: $z = x^2 + y^2$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can reproduce the figures as follow.

Lets work in frame of the table, which means that the position of paper sheet is $\vec r(t) = -(R_{table} \cos(\omega_{table} t + \phi_{table}), R_{table} \sin(\omega_{table} t))$ .

Now we add to it the offset of a pen which is $\vec {\delta r}(t) = (R_x \cos(\omega_x t + \phi_x), R_y \cos(\omega_y t + \phi_y))$ with all variables indexed x belonging to X-pendulum and so on.

Thus the full answer (position of the pen relative to the paper) would be

$ X(t) = R_{table} \cos(\omega_{table} t + \phi_{table}) + R_x \cos(\omega_x t + \phi_x)$

$Y(t) = R_{table} \sin(\omega_{table} t) + R_y \cos(\omega_y t + \phi_y)$

The final result is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uncle_dima/YVyCu/2/) and it mimics one of the pictures from [here](http://www.karlsims.com/harmonograph/index.html).

PS. We have neglected the tilt of the paper pad and corresponding geometry (i.e., assumed that paper is always parallel to the table), but IMHO it shouldn't change things dramatically.

Comment: Code mostly came from Saturnix, I just added the pad :-)

Comment: thanks! :) by modifying your code a little I got what I was searching for!